# How can a Power App added to a Teams meeting, read meeting information?

Tags: microsoft-teams, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am trying to create a power app and add it to a particular teams meeting. I want that power app to be able to get the meeting title and meeting members list when the meeting starts or when the PowerApp is added to a particular meeting in teams.

I have tried below things but it does not work:

- Teams Context Variable:

  - `Param("userPrincipalName")`
  - `Param("meetingTitle")`
- Microsoft Teams Integration Object. Usage: `Teams.ThisMeeting` (it has only one property called Id)
- Microsoft Teams Connector: Usage: `MicrosoftTeams.<objectName>` (nothing related to current meeting.)

Please help me out with this.

Comment: Hi @Garvit, 

Yes, you can get the meeting members list, could you please have a look on this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: @Rama-MSFT Hi, I checked the document, It shows a graph API call to get a particular callRecord: `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords/{id}` but it needs the meeting/call Id which I am not able to get from within the meeting. I need my Powerapp to be able to get the meeting information when meeting starts.

Comment: You can subscribe to call record notification API and get details of the meeting. Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0) Also check this [sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-webhooks-sample#microsoft-graph-change-notifications-sample-for-aspnet-core) for more info

Answer (score 0):

Moving answer from comments to answer section for better visibility.

You can subscribe to call record notification API and get details of the meeting. Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0) Also check this [sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-webhooks-sample#microsoft-graph-change-notifications-sample-for-aspnet-core) for more info.